# Advice on Web API accessing Microsoft Graph using tokens granted by Sign In's in another Web App

Tags: asp.net-mvc, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service, refresh-token, azure-api-apps

I am working on an infrastructure where Azure is central to the solution, but I would need suggestions or answers on particularly authentication flow, security, what is feasible or not, what might be problems etc. What I aim to do is the following:

A set of embedded devices need to get profile data from Microsoft accounts. Because of limited architecture, these devices will not implement authentication themselves. Neither can a browser be displayed on them to sign in users.

Each device makes requests to a public web api in Azure, which in turn makes authenticated calls to Graph using tokens stored in a table. Then profile data is returned back to the device from the api.

The tokens are granted and stored in a Azure Table (readable by the web api) via another web page (separate web app), where users have previously signed in with a Microsoft or work/school account and granted access to read profile data. That means that multiple users may have signed in and consented, so there will potentially be multiple tokens stored in the table.

What I'm not sure about is the best authentication flow to use, 
 whether I can just store the refresh token etc. Or whether there will be a problem with this architecture.

Would the on-behalf-of-flow be relevant?
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow
I am thinking that, in the protocol diagram, "application" would be the web app, "Web API A" would be the web api, and "Web API B" would be Graph API.
I've found this sample, that caches tokens to a database, which I'm looking at now: https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-aspnetcore-webapp-openidconnect-v2/tree/master/2-WebApp-graph-user/2-2-TokenCache

I've already managed to sign in users in the web app (using a different sample) and store the access token in a table shared with the api, and when I request my api, it uses these access tokens to make calls to Graph. This works, although I think it's better to use refresh tokens with longer expiration.

Relevant questions:

- Should the api that receives requests maintain sign in of users, and not the web app?
- How to store tokens in the database/Azure, to be used by the api project? Is storing a refresh token enough? Or use some token caching to a database?
- Libraries/packages to use.

Don't need a complete solution. Tips for parts of it would also be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: A proper way might be to make use of the device flow: https://www.oauth.com/oauth2-servers/device-flow/. It is supported by Azure: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-device-code - you can display messages on your embedded devices, right?

Comment: Device code flow is a good option. If that is also not possible, you might need to get the profile info in a back-end service that your device can call. You'd need to deal with the authentication between the device and your API somehow though.

Comment: @juunas yes, I am thinking the api can work as such a backend. Devices would make secure requests to it. I was thinking that the devices would have a device id or password that was sent with the requests, which would work as some sort of authentication.

Comment: @Dejan yes device flow might be a good option, at least for parts of it (sign in and get token). I will check this out. They can display messages. I still have some reasons to avoid calling Graph API directly from the devices though. Perhaps the tokens acquired through device flow can be sent with the request to my api, which then use them to request Graph Api…

Comment: You can acquire a token for your API on the device and use on-behalf-of in the API to exchange it for a Graph token

Comment: @Dejan I now manage to log in by device code flow using the user code the device receives. I can get basic profile information with the access token granted. However, I've tried a graph endpoint which return more data, then I get Status code 404: "ResourceNotFound" (Resource could not be discovered), even if user consents to the device accessing this data. I'm using personal account. Any ideas? (by the way I apologize for deleting and reposting some comments... could not edit after some minutes.. don't want to flood anyone with notifications :) )

Comment: @Morten you would have received status code 403 if your access token didn't contain the scopes required to access the requested data. The status code 404 means you're hitting an endpoint which doesn't exist. Also double check if you were supposed to call a beta endpoint, some information can only be accessed via those at the moment (Graph API documentation should get you to the right track).